# Is even divided by even a rational or irrational number?

Tags: arithmetic, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

For any rational number, $\frac{p}{q}$ , $p$ and $q$ should be integers, $q\neq0$ and $p,q$ should not have any common factors.
Now, if we have two even numbers, say $2m$ and $2n$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers.
$$\frac{\text{even}}{\text{even}}=\frac{2m}{2n}=\frac{m}{n}$$
where($\frac{m}{n}$) nature is still unknown.
So, what nature does $\frac{\text{even}}{\text{even}}$ have, rational or irrational?

additional reference: https://www.quora.com/Is-2-4-rational

Comment: What do you mean by "nature"?

Comment: A number is irrational if it cannot be expressed as a ratio. If the denominator is even or odd doesn't matter.

Comment: even / even is rational. (And denominator can't be 0 of course.)

Comment: I'll make a guess that OP defined rational numbers to be the ratio of two coprime integers with nonzero denominator. (Then, the confusion shouldn't only be about even numbers, though but also about other multiples.) In that case, you should recall prime factorization and cancel common multiple.

Comment: It seems like you were unfamiliar with the definition of a rational/irrational number before you asked this question. Any number that can be written as the fraction of one whole number divided by another whole (nonzero) number is rational (by definition!), and this has nothing to do with either or both of them being odd or even.

Comment: He's clearly very confused, but I don't see how there's anything unclear about what he's asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is that if you have $p$ and $q\neq 0$ integers then $|p|$ and $|q|$ are positive integers, or $p=0$ when $\frac pq=0$ is rational. If you cancel a common factor $2$ to obtain $|m|\lt p$ and $|n|\lt q$ you have smaller positive integers.

You can keep dividing common factors and obtain a decreasing sequence of positive integers for numerator, and another for denominator. Since a decreasing sequence of positive integers must eventually be constant this process will terminate in a (form of the) fraction in which numerator and denominator have no common positive integer factor apart from $1$. This is what you have defined as a rational number.

Answer (score 4):

If $m$ and $n$ are integers and $n \ne 0$, then $\frac{m}{n}$ is rational.

Comment: @AbbasMiya It doesn't matter whether the numbers are even or odd; the definition of a rational number is that it's one integer (whole number) divided by another (which is nonzero). Regardless of whether $m$ and $n$ are either odd or even, in both cases they will be an integer, so $\frac{m}{n}$ will always be rational.

Comment: @AbbasMiya All integers have a finite prime factorisation. Therefore, they have a largest number in common such that $n/k$ and $m/k$ are integers, but no larger $k$ works for that. We call that $\gcd(m, n)$. Then, we have that $n/k$ and $m/k$ are coprime (why?) and thus you have the fraction in the form you want it

Comment: So, what I learnt is for all fractions, it is possible to write the simplest form(lowest terms), with no common factors. After writing that, we can easily decide, if that number is a rational number.

Comment: @AbbasMiya "So, what I learnt is for all fractions, it is possible to write the simplest form(lowest terms), with no common factors. After writing that, we can easily decide, if that number is a rational number." No! I mean yes, but most of that is irrelevant. It sounds like you haven't been reading what people have written. We know automatically, **by definition**, that $1,435,387/256,676$ is rational - we don't need to reduce to lowest terms to determine that! Yes, any rational _can_ be reduced to lowest terms, but that has nothing to do with the definition.

Answer (score 1):

https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Proof_by_contradiction

Proof (by contradiction) that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

**Assume for a minute, that** $\sqrt{2}$ **is rational**, that is: it can be written as $\sqrt{2}=p/q$ for two specific integer numbers $p$ and $q$, **which don't share any common divisors greater than** $1$.

If now $\sqrt{2}=p/q$, then we can square to get $2=p^2/q^2$ or multiply both sides by $q^2$ and get $2q^2 = p^2$. Now the number $q^2$ is an integer, because $q$ is an integer, and the number $2q^2$ is an even number, because we are multiplying the integer $q^2$ by $2$ and the result of multiplication of any integer number by $2$ gives an even number.

If now $2q^2$ is an even number, then $p^2$ is an even number, because $2q^2=p^2$. Thus the number $p$ **is an even number**, because $p^2$ is an even number.

If now $p$ is an even number, then we can express it as $p=2k$ for some integer $k$ and if $p=2k$, then $p^2 = 4k^2$.

So, we get $q^2=2k^2$, because $2q^2=p^2$ and $p^2=4k^2$. If we have $q^2=2k^2$, then $q^2$ is an even number. If $q^2$ is an even number, then $q$ **is an even number**.

If $p$ is an even number and $q$ is an even number, then $p/q$ can be further simplified. This is a contradiction to the assumption, that $p$ and $q$ should not share any common divisors greater than $1$. Thus, the assumption is false, it's opposite is true. This means $\sqrt{2}$ must be irrational.